# Paddle game - Ball contacting paddle

Tags: java, methods, collision

Currently coding the java game where there are three walls and a paddle at the bottom, trying to implement the collision method that checks if the ball strikes the paddle. The ball sometimes notices the paddle, and sometimes doesn't. Wondering if someone could point me out where I'm going wrong.

My code:

```
public boolean isCollision(Ball aBall) {


int ballYPos = aBall.getY(); // getY will return position of center of ball
int paddleXPos = Paddle.this.getX(); //will return upper left corner of paddle

    if(ballYPos-aBall.getRadius() == paddleXPos+width ) //checking for yPos-radius
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are checking if they are the exact same. So it will only return true if they are exactly the same, ie. 10.1 == 10.1.... however 10.1 != 10.2

Try using

```
if(ballYPos-aBall.getRadius() <= paddleXPos+width ) //checking for yPos-radius
    {
        return true;
    }
```

However this seems like a clunky way to calculate it anyway. You are comparing the ball's Y value to the paddles X value.

Comment: if I substitute paddleXPos+width to the paddles height, it will always change directions at the height, regardless of if the paddle is there or not. Thats the only way I know how to incorporate the Y value. I'm really stuck on this method.